# How to include un-numbered sections in additional ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, nomenclature

This is a follow-up question to: [Contents page in two different languages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170912/contents-page-in-two-different-languages/170963?noredirect=1#comment395114_170963)

Now with a working second language table of contents I have tried including parts of the article such as the table of figures, tables and nomenclature. This is the code that works to achieve the second ToC.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,pdftexcmds}
\let\englishtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\patchcmd\englishtableofcontents{{toc}}{{tec}}{}{}
\preto\englishtableofcontents{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}}
\appto\englishtableofcontents{\end{otherlanguage}}

\let\englishlistoffigures\listoffigures
\patchcmd\englishlistoffigures{{lof}}{{lef}}{}{}
\preto\englishlistoffigures{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}}
\appto\englishlistoffigures{\end{otherlanguage}}

\let\englishlistoftables\listoftables
\patchcmd\englishlistoftables{{lot}}{{let}}{}{}
\preto\englishlistoftables{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}}
\appto\englishlistoftables{\end{otherlanguage}}

\newcommand{\addetoc}[2]{%
  \addcontentsline{tec}{#1}{\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}#2}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\englishcaption}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\@captype}{figure}=\z@
    \addcontentsline{lef}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#1}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{let}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

In order to add in the sections I have included simply the following line after printing the nomenclature:

```
\printnomenclature
\addetoc{section}{Nomenclature}
```

This however includes it as a section with the number '0.' since it occurs before the ToC itself. How could I, for example, do the equivalent of a \section* within this function so I have no section number appearing in the ToC of the second language.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of using `\addetoc`, you could directly use `\addcontentsline{tec}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Nomenclature}`

Answer (score 5):

It's probably better to act on the `\thenomenclature` command; adding `\addetoc` after `\printnomenclature` will give the wrong result if the nomenclature is more than one page long.

```
\makeatletter
\def\thenomenclature{%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}%
  {
    \section*{\nomname}
    \if@intoc
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}%
      \addcontentsline{tec}{section}{Nomenclature}%
    \fi
  }%
  {
    \chapter*{\nomname}
    \if@intoc
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}%
      \addcontentsline{tec}{chapter}{Nomenclature}%
    \fi
  }%

  \nompreamble
  \list{}{%
    \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \itemsep\nomitemsep
    \let\makelabel\nomlabel}}
\makeatother
```

With `etoolbox` it's a bit easier:

```
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\addcontentsline{tec}{section}{Nomenclature}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\addcontentsline{tec}{chapter}{Nomenclature}}
  {}{}
```