# Two tables of contents one in Chinese and another in English

Tags: table-of-contents, chinese, content-replication

I want to give two tables of contents one in Chinese and another in English in my `ctexbook` document class which is used most widely in writing Chinese book nowadays. Here we collect different solutions to the problem.

Comment: Similar: an article from zhihu.com (in Chinese) https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/73527391

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I copied the codes from the related link into the following post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The new solution (2022-05-28)

[The new solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645829/140814) which is improved by @Tom and me based on my old solution may be the best one so far as now.

Note: The new solution gives a way to add *more contents in other languages*, i.e., you could add some contents in French, German, Greek and so on by defining different contents-adding commands like `\entableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{ctexbook}

\ctexset{chapter/number=\arabic{chapter}}%change number format in Chinese \tableofcontents
\usepackage{etoolbox}%\apptocmd
\usepackage{calc}%\widthof
%%%define \entableofcontents%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\encontentsname}{Contents}
\newcommand\entableofcontents{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \else
    \@restonecolfalse
  \fi
  \chapter*{%
    \encontentsname
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\encontentsname}
            {\MakeUppercase\encontentsname}%
  }%
  \@starttoc{entoc}%
  \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\newcommand{\enchapapp}{Chapter}
\apptocmd{\appendix}{\renewcommand{\enchapapp}{Appendix}}{}{}
\newcommand{\addentoc}[2]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{entoc}{#1}{\setlength\@tempdima{\widthof{\textbf{Appendix\space{M}\space}}}\protect\numberline{\enchapapp\space\thechapter}#2}}%
  {\addcontentsline{entoc}{#1}{\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}#2}}%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\entableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter*{凡例}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{凡例}
\addcontentsline{entoc}{chapter}{Styles}

\chapter{引言}
\addentoc{chapter}{Introduction}

\chapter{引言}
\addentoc{chapter}{Introduction}

\chapter{引言}
\addentoc{chapter}{Introduction}

\chapter{引言}
\addentoc{chapter}{Introduction}

\chapter{引言}
\addentoc{chapter}{Introduction}

\chapter{引言}
\addentoc{chapter}{Introduction}

\chapter{引言}
\addentoc{chapter}{Introduction}

\chapter{引言}
\addentoc{chapter}{Introduction}

\chapter{引言}
\addentoc{chapter}{Introduction}

\section{方法和材料}
\addentoc{section}{Methods and materials}

\begin{appendix}
\chapter{理论}
\addentoc{chapter}{Theory}
\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

### The old solution (2022-05-27)

I search in the cite for about similar questions, and find [one undesired solution (while thanks still go to @egreg)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170963/140814) which couldn't be used by me since the `babel` package has no `chinese` option. While I get one desired solution by improving that undesired solution. Now I post it here.

Note: The solution is also useful when to *add two contents in two other languages (one is in the main language, for example German, and another is in another language, for example, English or Greek)* and takes less packages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{ctexbook}

%%%define \entableofcontents%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\encontentsname}{Contents}
\newcommand\entableofcontents{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
  \else
    \@restonecolfalse
  \fi
  \chapter*{%
    \encontentsname
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\encontentsname}
            {\MakeUppercase\encontentsname}%
  }%
  \@starttoc{entoc}%
  \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
}
\newcommand{\addentoc}[2]{%
  \addcontentsline{entoc}{#1}{\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}#2}%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\entableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter*{凡例}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{凡例}
\addcontentsline{entoc}{chapter}{Styles}

\chapter{引言}
\addentoc{chapter}{Introduction}

\section{方法和材料}
\addentoc{section}{Methods and materials}

\end{document}
```

The output to the two contents by XeLaTeX is as follows.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which is provided by @muzimuzhi Z and from [the link](https://github.com/muzimuzhi/latex-examples/blob/master/examples/bilingual-toc.tex). Note, the `tocloft` package is used in the solution.

```
% ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170963/79060
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\def\en@toc@ext{tec}
\def\en@contentsname{Contents}


%% two user commands
\newcommand\enTableOfContents{
  \begingroup
    % restore \contentsname
    \let\contentsname\en@contentsname
    % restore behavior of \numberline
    \let\CTEX@toc@width@n\@gobble
    % adjust numwidth (required by long section numbers)
    \addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{.3em}
    \addtolength\cftsecnumwidth{.5em}
    \addtolength\cftsubsecnumwidth{.8em}
    % output en-toc
    \@enTableOfContents
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand\enSectionTitle[1]{
  \def\@currentTitle{#1}
  \ignorespaces
}


%% provide \@enTableOfContents
\let\@enTableOfContents\tableofcontents
\@ifundefined {chapter}
  { % e.g., article.cls
    \xpatchcmd\@enTableOfContents
      {\@starttoc{toc}}
      {\endgroup\@starttoc{\en@toc@ext}}
      {}{\fail}
  }
  { % e.g., book.cls
    \xpatchcmd\@enTableOfContents
      {\chapter}
      {
        \begingroup
        % restore to ctex's "scheme=plain"
        \ctexset{
          chapter/format = \Huge\bfseries\raggedright
        }
        \chapter
      }
      {}{\fail}
    \xpatchcmd\@enTableOfContents
      {\@starttoc{toc}}
      {\endgroup\@starttoc{\en@toc@ext}}
      {}{\fail}
  }

%% modify to write two toc entries
\cs_set_protected:Npn \CTEX@addtocline #1#2
  {
    % write cn-toc entry
    \addcontentsline { toc } {#1}
      { \use:c { CTEX@#1@tocline } {#1} {#2} }
    \begingroup
      % restore to ctex's "scheme=plain"
      \ctexset{
        part/name      = {Part\space,},
        part/number    = \Roman{part},
      }
      \@ifundefined {chapter}
        {}
        {
          \ctexset{
            chapter/name   = {,},
            chapter/number = \arabic{chapter}
          }
        }
      % write en-toc entry
      \addcontentsline \en@toc@ext {#1}
        { \use:c { CTEX@#1@tocline } {#1} { \@currentTitle } }
    \endgroup
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\enTableOfContents

\enSectionTitle{Main body}
\part{正文}

\enSectionTitle{Introduction}
\chapter{介绍}

\setcounter{chapter}{10}

\enSectionTitle{Introduction 2}
\chapter{介绍}

\enSectionTitle{Method and materials}
\section{方法和材料}

\setcounter{section}{9}
\enSectionTitle{Method and materials 2}
\section{方法和材料 2}

\enSectionTitle{Data compilation}
\subsection{数据搜集}

\setcounter{subsection}{9}
\enSectionTitle{Data compilation 2}
\subsection{数据搜集 2}

\setcounter{part}{12}
\enSectionTitle{Appendix}
\part{附录}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]